# Testing Ajax on Django

Tags: python, django, ajax, django-testing, django-tests

I'm trying to write a test for an Ajax get a request in Django.
Here's how I tried.

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls import reverse
from .models import ResourcePost, User
from register.models import DonorProfile
from django.utils import timezone

class getResourcePostTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        ResourcePost.objects.create(
            title="test1",
            description="test",
            quantity=10,
            dropoff_time_1=timezone.now(),
            dropoff_time_2=timezone.now(),
            dropoff_time_3=timezone.now(),
            date_created=timezone.now(),
            donor=createdonor_1(),
            resource_category="FOOD",
            status="AVAILABLE",
        )
        ...
                   
    def test_getResourcePost(self):
        rescource_post_1 = ResourcePost.objects.get(title="test1")
        rescource_post_2 = ResourcePost.objects.get(title="test2")
        rescource_post_3 = ResourcePost.objects.get(title="test3")

        response = self.client.get(reverse('donation:getResourcePosts'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Here is my view for the ajax call:

```
@login_required
def getResourcePost(request):
    user = request.user

    curr_user_rc_1 = user.helpseekerprofile.rc_1
    curr_user_rc_2 = user.helpseekerprofile.rc_2
    curr_user_rc_3 = user.helpseekerprofile.rc_3

    posts = ResourcePost.objects.all()
    passingList = []
    for post in posts:
        if post.date_created >= user.helpseekerprofile.message_timer_before and (
            post.resource_category == curr_user_rc_1
            or post.resource_category == curr_user_rc_2
            or post.resource_category == curr_user_rc_3
        ):
            notiPost = {
                "id": post.id,
                "title": post.title,
                "description": post.description,
            }
            passingList.append(notiPost)
    context = {"resource_posts": passingList}

    return JsonResponse(context)
```

This is my ajax code:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(() => {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "{% url 'donation:getResourcePosts' %}",
        success: function (response) {
          $("#display").html('<i class="fas fa-bell"></i>')
          let postCounter = 0
          for (i = 0; i < response.resource_posts.length; i++) {
            postCounter += 1
          }
          if (postCounter > 0) {
            $("#display").append('<span class="message-number">' + postCounter + '</span>')
          }
        },
        error: function (response) {
          console.log("No DATA FOUND")
        }
      })
    }, 1000 * 2)
  })
```

I keep getting fail because the reponse is 302.

1. Why am I not getting 200? How can I fix this to get 200?
2. The variables `rescource_post_X` come up as variables not used. How do I use them? Should I use them?

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps since you have the login required decorator it is directing you to the login page.

Is your IDE complaining about the objects not being used? Not entirely important. It's just reminding you that you are allocating resources that may not be needed.

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept my answer so future visitors may easily find the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The @login_required decorator is redirecting your request to the login page